# User session not Maintain when Integrated a website into another website with object, embed or iframe tag

Tags: html, asp.net, session, iframe, object-tag

I have a website-A with login and create account. Once user logged in, it maintains a user session until the customer logs out.
I have an another website-B which needs to integrate Website-A.
When customer is in Website-B and login to Website-A, we need to maintain user session created in Website-A until the customer logs out.

I tried to integrate Website-A using OBJECT , EMBED or IFRAME tag in Website-B. But after customer logs in, immediately the user is logged out from website.

Anyone came across this scenario and fixed? Please share it.

Thanks for reading and hoping to solve this problem sooner .